# Update the year column in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a date in the format `DD-MMM-YY` (not timestamp) e.g 12-Dec-2021 I just want to update the year and make it like 12-Dec-2019.

I'm trying this code but I get an error:

> ORA-01821: date format not recognized ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SQL", line 1721

This is my SQL:

```
UPDATE employees 
SET date_hired = TO_DATE('11-Dec-12', 'DD-MMM-YY') 
WHERE cost_center = 86;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `MON` in the format mask for a three letter abbreviated month name:

```sql
UPDATE employees 
SET date_hired = TO_DATE('11-Dec-12', 'DD-MON-YY') 
WHERE cost_center = 86;
```

Note that you could also use an ANSI date literal:

```sql
UPDATE employees 
SET date_hired = date '2012-12-11'
WHERE cost_center = 86;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. How can i use date in where clause . I am using UPDATE employees 
SET date_hired = TO_DATE('11-Dec-12', 'DD-MON-YY') 
WHERE date_hired = TO_DATE('11-Mar-2019','DD-MON-YY'); but no records are getting updated

Comment: First run the equivalent select: `SELECT * FROM employees WHERE date_hired = date '2019-03-11'` ... do you see any records?  If not, then the update also won't do anything.

Comment: Note, that for `MON` and `DAY` format elements it would be better to use `NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=AMERICAN` explicitly as the third argument for `to_date`. ANSI date literal is the most straightforward way